# Ado.Net Entity Data Model does not appear on item page in Visual Studio 2022 Asp MVC Project

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, entity, .net-7.0

Ado.Net Entity Data Model does not appear on item page in Visual Studio 2022 Asp MVC Project
FrameWork= .:Net 7.0 Please help. Thanks.

[image]

to

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Creating an ADO.NET Entity Data Model is not supported within a .NET Core interface; it's exclusively available through the .NET Framework. To proceed, you must adjust your target framework to either .NET Framework 4.8 or an earlier version.

If you wish to generate your model and context from the database, you should utilize Entity Framework Core scaffolding tools, which are accessible through either the command-line interface (CLI) or Package Manager Console (PMC).